# wkhtmltopdf Header, Image & Pagenumbers

Tags: c#, wkhtmltopdf

I want to add a Header to my PDF with this:
--header-center TEST

and it works fine, but if i want to insert Whitespace:
--header-center TEST test

it wont be displayed. Do I have to write something instead of " "?

Another question is how to insert pagenumbers into the footer. I found this code-snippet, but I'm new in this issue and have no idea how to implement it:

```
var pdfInfo = {}; 
  var x = document.location.search.substring(1).split('&'); 
  for (var i in x) { var z = x[i].split('=',2); pdfInfo[z[0]] = unescape(z[1]); } 
  function getPdfInfo() { 
    var page = pdfInfo.page || 1; 
    var pageCount = pdfInfo.topage || 1; 
    document.getElementById('pdfkit_page_current').textContent = page; 
    document.getElementById('pdfkit_page_count').textContent = pageCount; 
  }
```

And my last question is how to insert Images into the footer with --header-html ~\image.html.
I inserted a link referencing a simple html with a picture but it wont be displayed.

I know... many questions. This issue is very tricky for me.

Thanks in advance!

LG FG

Comment: I can't help you with the page numbers, but for the space you need to surround the text in quotes, ex. --header-center "TEST test".  The image in the image.html has to be the absolute URL to the image, and you'll have to resize the page margins to make sure it fits, ex. "--margin-top 25mm" (it defaults to 10mm)

Answer (score 2):

As in my comment, the whitespace in the text header should work if you surround it in quotes, ex `--header-center "TEST test"`

Okay, so I played around and found how to get the page numbers and image to work.  Your header.html should look something like (notice how the image URL is the absolute path) :

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var pdfInfo = {};
        var x = document.location.search.substring(1).split('&');
        for (var i in x) { var z = x[i].split('=',2); pdfInfo[z[0]] = unescape(z[1]); }
        function getPdfInfo() {
            var page = pdfInfo.page || 1;
            var pageCount = pdfInfo.topage || 1;
            document.getElementById('pdfkit_page_current').textContent = page;
            document.getElementById('pdfkit_page_count').textContent = pageCount;
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="getPdfInfo()">
    <img src="/var/sites/mysite/htdocs/images/logo.jpg" />
    <br />Page <span id="pdfkit_page_current"></span> Of <span id="pdfkit_page_count"></span>
</body>
</html>
```

Then generate the with something like `wkhtmltopdf --margin-top 40mm --header-html /var/sites/mysite/pdf/header.html content.html output.pdf`

You'll have to play with --margin-top to get the right spacing.  The same procedure should work for footers as well.

My source for this was http://metaskills.net/2011/03/20/pdfkit-overview-and-advanced-usage/ (PDFkit is a wrapper for wkhtmltopdf)

Comment: The [wkhtmltopdf manual](http://tinyurl.com/wk2pdfmanual) also holds very good example that I currently use also holds very good example that I currently use.

Comment: You must add <!DOCTYPE html> to the html header/footer, otherwise it produces a blank page